# Python change to geotagged photos to kml and csv (remove labels)

Tags: kml, photos

I am writing from NC in the aftermath of Hurricane Florence. I have been working with a Python Script for geotagged photos. If there is anyone out there willing to look over a short two-page script and possibly contribute to helping out folks here in NC

I am novice at Python and I am trying to remove the image name (or the label all together)

```
import sys, traceback, os 
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
import simplekml
from easygui import  *
kml = simplekml.Kml()

def get_exif(fn):
    ret = {}
    i = Image.open(fn)
    try:
        info = i._getexif()

        for t, v in info.items():
            try:
                decoded = TAGS.get(t, t)
                ret[decoded] = v
            except:
                pass
        if "GPSInfo" in ret:
            return ret["GPSInfo"]
        else:
            return {}
    except:
        return {}

def process_gps(tags):
    gps = {}
    if (tags != None) and (1 in tags) and (not tags[1] == "\x00"): # 1 and 3 are not present if the coords keys are not present and will be null if no coords
        gps["y"] = dmsdec(tags[2][0][0], tags[2][0][1], tags[2][1][0], tags[2][1][1], tags[2][2][0], tags[2][2][1], tags[1])
        gps["x"] = dmsdec(tags[4][0][0], tags[4][0][1], tags[4][1][0], tags[4][1][1], tags[4][2][0], tags[4][2][1], tags[3])
    return gps

def dmsdec(dn, dd, mn, md, sn, sd, o="N"):
    degree = float(dn)/float(dd)
    minute = float(mn)/float(md)/60
    second = float(sn)/float(sd)/3600
    coord = degree + minute + second
    if(o == "S" or o == "W"):
        coord = coord * -1
    return coord

def get_exif_data(fname):
    """Get embedded EXIF image width, height, and data from image file."""
    ret = {}
    ret2 = {}
    try:
        img = Image.open(fname)
        if hasattr( img, '_getexif' ):
            exifinfo = img._getexif()
            if exifinfo != None:
                for tag, value in exifinfo.items():

                    decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
                    ret[decoded] = value
    except IOError:
        print 'IOERROR ' + fname

    try:
        return [ret['ImageWidth'], ret['ImageLength'],ret['DateTime']]
    except:
        return [ret['ExifImageWidth'], ret['ExifImageHeight'],ret['DateTimeOriginal']]


def get_AltAndAzi(fname):
    import PIL
    img = PIL.Image.open(fname)
    exif_data = img._getexif()
    exif = {PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v
    for k, v in img._getexif().items()
    if k in PIL.ExifTags.TAGS}
    try:
        alt = int(exif['GPSInfo'][6][0]/exif['GPSInfo'][6][1]*3.28084)
    except:
        alt = "No altitude data for this image."
    try:
        azi =  int(exif['GPSInfo'][17][0]/exif['GPSInfo'][17][1])
    except:
        azi = "No camera azimuth data for this image."
    return(alt, azi)

def fDecantonate(s1, s2):
    '''removes the string s1 from the front of string s2'''
    s1l = len(s1)
    if s1 == s2[:s1l]:
        return s2[s1l:]
    else:
        return "fDecantonate failed! Strings do not match, decantonation not possible." 

def ColorNameToHex(incolor):
    "print wait..."
    #print "incolor = ",incolor
    colors = {}
    colors["white"] = 'ffFFFFFF'
    colors["gray"] = 'ff5a5a5a'
    colors["black"] = 'ff000000'
    colors["red"] = 'ff1400be'
    colors["orange"] = 'ff1478ff'
    colors["yellow"] = 'ff14f0e6'
    colors["green"] = 'ff507800'
    colors["blue"] = 'ff785000'
    colors["purple"] = 'ff783278'
    colors["brown"] = 'ff143c5a'

    if incolor in colors:
        return colors[incolor]
    else:
        print "Icon color choice not valid, using default"
        return 'ff1478ff'
##########   input Parameters  ########################
inDir = diropenbox("Set to the input directory of geo-tagged images.  This directory will also store the output KML file.")
projectName = enterbox("Enter a Project Name.  The output KML will be named ProjectName_KML.KML", "Create KML file for all geo-tagged images (jpg) in a directory.","ProjectName")
incolor = choicebox(msg='Pick a text color.', title="Create KML File for all geo-tagged images (jpg) in a directory.", choices=("white", "black" , "gray", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "brown"))

#######################################################

outKML = inDir+"\\"+ projectName + "_kml.kml"
outCSV = inDir+"\\"+ projectName + "_csv.csv"

#remove any existing csv file from the directory, create a new file, and write the csv header
if os.path.isfile(outCSV):
    os.remove(outCSV)
f = open(outCSV,'a')
f.writelines('x,y,imagename,fullpath,imagedate\n')



#Set the color for the kml pin labels...
textcolor = ColorNameToHex(incolor)


for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(inDir):
    for inFile in filenames:
        if inFile.endswith('.jpg') or inFile.endswith('.JPG'):

            if dirpath == inDir:
                relativePath = inFile
                fullpath = dirpath + "\\"+ inFile
            else:
                relativePath = fDecantonate(inDir, dirpath)+"\\"+ inFile
                relativePath = relativePath[1:]
                fullpath = dirpath + "\\"+ inFile
            try:
                aa = get_AltAndAzi(fullpath)
                exifstuff = get_exif_data(fullpath)
                theTags = get_exif(fullpath)
                theCoords = process_gps(theTags)
                tupleCoords =  (theCoords['x'], theCoords['y'])

            except:
                print "No geotag information.  Image skipped: ", fullpath

            else:
                print "Creating point data for: ", fullpath
                relativePath = relativePath.replace(".JPG", ".jpg")
                thetext ='<img src="'+ relativePath + '" height="' + str(exifstuff[1]/4) + '" width="' + str(exifstuff[0]/4)+\
                '" alt="path failed"/>'+ '<br>Project Name: '+ projectName+ \
                '<br>Image Capture Date & Time: '+exifstuff[2]+\
                '<br>Camera Azimuth(deg): '+ str(aa[1])+ \
                '<br>GPS Elevation(ft):' + str(aa[0])+ \
                '<br>Image Location and File Name:'+ relativePath+\
                "<br><br>Geotagged Images to KML & CSV  - Created by Gerry Gabrisch (gerry@gabrisch.us) 2015"




                pnt = kml.newpoint(name= inFile, coords=[tupleCoords])
                pnt.style.iconstyle.icon.href ="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle.png"
                pnt.style.labelstyle.color = textcolor


                pnt.style.balloonstyle.text = thetext
                pnt.style.balloonstyle.bgcolor = simplekml.Color.white
                pnt.style.balloonstyle.textcolor = simplekml.Color.black

                f.writelines(str(theCoords['x'])+","+ str(theCoords['y']) +"," + inFile +"," + fullpath +","+  exifstuff[2]+","+ '\n')

kml.save(outKML)
f.close()                

print "Done Without Errors"
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a new version of the tool to github that does not add labels to the points in the KML. The link points to a compiled version of the code using Py2exe and so it is a bit of a hack but you do not need Python or the add-in libraries to make it work.

The change was simple with just a line of code added. I removed the option to choose a label text color as well.

```
pnt.style.labelstyle.scale = 0
```

Here is a link to the tool. https://github.com/gerry1138/Geo-Tagged-Photos-to-KML-and-CSV-.  The site editors will scold me if I do not add the raw code so...

```
import sys, traceback, os 
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
import simplekml
from easygui import  *
kml = simplekml.Kml()

def get_exif(fn):
    ret = {}
    i = Image.open(fn)
    try:
        info = i._getexif()

        for t, v in info.items():
            try:
                decoded = TAGS.get(t, t)
                ret[decoded] = v
            except:
                pass
        if "GPSInfo" in ret:
            return ret["GPSInfo"]
        else:
            return {}
    except:
        return {}

def process_gps(tags):
    gps = {}
    if (tags != None) and (1 in tags) and (not tags[1] == "\x00"): # 1 and 3 are not present if the coords keys are not present and will be null if no coords
        gps["y"] = dmsdec(tags[2][0][0], tags[2][0][1], tags[2][1][0], tags[2][1][1], tags[2][2][0], tags[2][2][1], tags[1])
        gps["x"] = dmsdec(tags[4][0][0], tags[4][0][1], tags[4][1][0], tags[4][1][1], tags[4][2][0], tags[4][2][1], tags[3])
    return gps

def dmsdec(dn, dd, mn, md, sn, sd, o="N"):
    degree = float(dn)/float(dd)
    minute = float(mn)/float(md)/60
    second = float(sn)/float(sd)/3600
    coord = degree + minute + second
    if(o == "S" or o == "W"):
        coord = coord * -1
    return coord

def get_exif_data(fname):
    """Get embedded EXIF image width, height, and data from image file."""
    ret = {}
    ret2 = {}
    try:
        img = Image.open(fname)
        if hasattr( img, '_getexif' ):
            exifinfo = img._getexif()
            if exifinfo != None:
                for tag, value in exifinfo.items():

                    decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
                    ret[decoded] = value
    except IOError:
        print 'IOERROR ' + fname

    try:
        return [ret['ImageWidth'], ret['ImageLength'],ret['DateTime']]
    except:
        return [ret['ExifImageWidth'], ret['ExifImageHeight'],ret['DateTimeOriginal']]


def get_AltAndAzi(fname):
    import PIL
    img = PIL.Image.open(fname)
    exif_data = img._getexif()
    exif = {PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v
    for k, v in img._getexif().items()
    if k in PIL.ExifTags.TAGS}
    try:
        alt = int(exif['GPSInfo'][6][0]/exif['GPSInfo'][6][1]*3.28084)
    except:
        alt = "No altitude data for this image."
    try:
        azi =  int(exif['GPSInfo'][17][0]/exif['GPSInfo'][17][1])
    except:
        azi = "No camera azimuth data for this image."
    return(alt, azi)

def fDecantonate(s1, s2):
    '''removes the string s1 from the front of string s2'''
    s1l = len(s1)
    if s1 == s2[:s1l]:
        return s2[s1l:]
    else:
        return "fDecantonate failed! Strings do not match, decantonation not possible." 




textbox("A Two-Bit Algoriths hack, copyright 2015, Gerry Gabrisch (gerry@gabrisch.us)","Create KML file for all geo-tagged images (jpg) in a directory.",\
"Click OK to create KML/CSV or read below.\n\n\n\
This tool will take a directory of geo-tagged images (including images in             any subdirectories) and \
it will create both a KML file and a CSV file in that directory. \
 The output KML file can be opened in Google Earth and each image will \
be referenced by a Google Earth icon (a black and white target).  Each \
icon is labeled with the image name using a user defined text color. \
Clicking on an icon in Google Earth will open a balloon box displaying \
the image, the image path relative to the kml, the image capture date, \
camera azimuth, and GNSS elevation.\n\n\
The csv file can be imported into qGIS or ArcGIS with coordinates in WGS84.\n\n\
USER INPUTS\n\n\
1. A directory of images.\n\
2. A project name (will be used to name the output files).\n\n\
Position accuracy is affected by weather, terrain, atmosphere, satellite availability, \
and electronics.  The positions recorded by this tool are extracted from the positions \
recorded by your device.  Positional accuracy is not guaranteed.  You can improve your \
location accuracy by letting your GNSS run prior to capturing images.  Check your location \
in a mapping app like Google Maps to ensure your GNSS is recording your correct location \
before capturing imagery with your device.\n\n\n\
This software is provided AS-IS, without warranty of any kind, expressed or implied, including \
but not limited to the warranties of merchantability, fitness for a particular purpose and \
noninfringment.  In no event shall the authors or copyright holders be liable of any claim, \
damages, or other liability, whether in an action of contract, tort or otherwise, arising \
from, out of or in connection with the software of the use or other dealings in the software.\


##########   input Parameters  ########################
inDir = diropenbox("Set to the input directory of geo-tagged images.  This directory will also store the output KML file.")
projectName = enterbox("Enter a Project Name.  The output KML will be named ProjectName_KML.KML", "Create KML file for all geo-tagged images (jpg) in a directory.","ProjectName")


#######################################################

outKML = inDir+"\\"+ projectName + "_kml.kml"
outCSV = inDir+"\\"+ projectName + "_csv.csv"

#remove any existing csv file from the directory, create a new file, and write the csv header
if os.path.isfile(outCSV):
    os.remove(outCSV)
f = open(outCSV,'a')
f.writelines('x,y,imagename,fullpath,imagedate\n')





for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(inDir):
    for inFile in filenames:
        if inFile.endswith('.jpg') or inFile.endswith('.JPG'):

            if dirpath == inDir:
                relativePath = inFile
                fullpath = dirpath + "\\"+ inFile
            else:
                relativePath = fDecantonate(inDir, dirpath)+"\\"+ inFile
                relativePath = relativePath[1:]
                fullpath = dirpath + "\\"+ inFile
            try:
                aa = get_AltAndAzi(fullpath)
                exifstuff = get_exif_data(fullpath)
                theTags = get_exif(fullpath)
                theCoords = process_gps(theTags)
                tupleCoords =  (theCoords['x'], theCoords['y'])

            except:
                print "No geotag information.  Image skipped: ", fullpath

            else:
                print "Creating point data for: ", fullpath
                relativePath = relativePath.replace(".JPG", ".jpg")
                thetext ='<img src="'+ relativePath + '" height="' + str(exifstuff[1]/4) + '" width="' + str(exifstuff[0]/4)+\
                '" alt="path failed"/>'+ '<br>Project Name: '+ projectName+ \
                '<br>Image Capture Date & Time: '+exifstuff[2]+\
                '<br>Camera Azimuth(deg): '+ str(aa[1])+ \
                '<br>GPS Elevation(ft):' + str(aa[0])+ \
                '<br>Image Location and File Name:'+ relativePath+\
                "<br><br>Geotagged Images to KML & CSV  - Created by Gerry Gabrisch (gerry@gabrisch.us) 2015"




                pnt = kml.newpoint(name= inFile, coords=[tupleCoords])
                pnt.style.iconstyle.icon.href ="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle.png"
                pnt.style.labelstyle.color = simplekml.Color.red
                pnt.style.labelstyle.scale = 0

                pnt.style.balloonstyle.text = thetext
                pnt.style.balloonstyle.bgcolor = simplekml.Color.white
                pnt.style.balloonstyle.textcolor = simplekml.Color.black

                f.writelines(str(theCoords['x'])+","+ str(theCoords['y']) +"," + inFile +"," + fullpath +","+  exifstuff[2]+","+ '\n')

kml.save(outKML)
f.close()                

print "Done Without Errors"
```